# Как открыть сайт, поднятый с помощью Vagrant vvv2, с других устройств?

Tags: сеть, ip, localhost, vagrant, browsersync

Я запустил свой сайт на локалке (мак ос) с помощью vagrant vvv2, но теперь встал вопрос как его тестировать на других устройствах в той же локальной сети? Ранее я это делал с помощью browser-sync, когда сайты были просто статичные (без всякого ВП движка). Я находил разные ответы на этот вопрос, но они мне не помогли, возможно потому что они относились к vvv1 (первая сборка).

Подскажите, есть ли боле-мене нормальный способ решить мою задачу путем каких то корректировок на локалке или в VM, возможно с прикручиванием того же browser-sync ? И в сетях я плохо разбираюсь, желательно чуть подробней)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою задачу с помщью browser-sync как описано здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023331/how-do-i-use-vagrant-and-browsersync-with-local-domain

Единственное, у меня не сработала функция автоматической перезагрузки страниц при изменении файлов, но в моей задаче этого не требовалось, но раз уж подключил browser-sync, то ее нужно будет тоже как то починить :)